# Calculation of the power of the difference of two matrices (Proof of Hamilton-Cayley theorem)

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, cayley-hamilton

I am having trouble with a proof of the Hamilton-Cayley theorem (in the case the square matrix is diagonalisable).

$$
A=SDS^{-1} $$ $$
p_{A}(A)=(A-\lambda _{1}I)^{r_{1}}...(A-\lambda _{k}I)^{r_{k}} $$ $$
p_{A}(A)=S(D-\lambda _{1}I)^{r_{1}}...(D-\lambda _{k}I)^{r_{k}}S^{-1}
$$

Where D is the diagonal matrix, the lambdas are the eigenvalues and p_A(A) is the characterstic polynomial of A.

In perticular I am having trouble understanding why when you replace A with SDS^-1 you can just take S and S^-1 out of the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have $A=SDS^{-1}$, we can easily take powers of $A$.  For instance,
\begin{equation}
A^2=(SDS^{-1})(SDS^{-1}) = SDS^{-1}SDS^{-1} = SDIDS^{-1} = SD^2S^{-1}.
\end{equation}
Next, you should verify that $A^n=SD^nS^{-1}$, as well as that $A^n+A^m = S(D^n+D^m)S^{-1}$ for any $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$.  Building up like this, eventually you can conclude that
\begin{equation}
p(A) = S~p(D)~S^{-1}
\end{equation}
for *any* polynomial $p$ (not just the characteristic polynomial).